# How do I find the Interface Inheritance Hierarchy For a type?

Tags: c#, interface, hierarchy

My purpose is to find out if a class implements an interface directly. In the example below, class B implements interface IB and interface IB implements IA.

How do I find out the inheritance hierarchy? When we view a type in Object Browser, it shows a detailed hierarchy. How can I achieve similar result?

```
interface IA
{
    string Member1 { get;set; }
}

interface IB : IA
{
    string Member2 { get; set; }
}

class B : IB
{
    public string Member1 { get; set; }
    public string Member2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Reflector Screenshot**

[alt text http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/7485/49211426.png](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/7485/49211426.png)

In the screenshot taken from reflector it shows the hierarchy of the interfaces as well.

How can I find out the interface hierarchy for a Type.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx

Comment: BaseType of B (typeof(B).BaseType) would return Object

Comment: In which case you know it is not inherited by any other types and you can check the interfaces themselves... Like with the `Type.GetInterfaces Method` (you can call it recursively to get all the interfaces - not really effective, but works).

Comment: GetInterfaces will return all the interfaces. For B it will return { IA, IB }.

Now to build a hierarchy the only possibility I see is to build a hierarchy myself by looping through each Interface and find out which interface implements which interface.

Whether this is the only solution or there is any better solution for this problem?

Comment: I have to ask this, unless you are building a reflector clone, why do you care? I don't mean to be snotty - I'm just curious, since worrying about this feels like it might be a code smell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflection and the .NET core are built to make interfaces fast to use.  Thus, Type.GetInterfaces returns all the interfaces that the type can respond to, "flattening" the interface hierarchy in the process.

If you want to divine the ancestry of those interfaces, you will need to call GetInterfaces on each interface as well.  There is no shortcut because the hierarchy of interfaces is of little value to the CLR runtime.